# "System.ObjectDisposedException" on async getting data from db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-core

When I'm trying to get some data from db async, I'm getting next error:

`Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances. Object name: AsyncDisposer`

in this method:

```
private async List<SomeData> TestData()
{
   var testData = await _cache.GetAsync<List<SomeData>("TestData");

        if (testData == null)
        {
            var testData = await MyDbContext.SomeDatas.ToListAsync();

            await _cache.SetAsync<List<SomeData>("TestData", testData);
        }
   return testData;
}
```

Exception is down at `ToListAsync()`, but without async method, everything works fine.

DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<SomeData> SomeDatas { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new SomeDataConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class SomeDataConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SomeData>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SomeData> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("SomeDatas");

        builder.Property(e => e.Value)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this requires a little bit more context, such as the method this statement is inside of and the method that calls it.

Comment: In your case method caller should be async. I mean: `async void GetData() { ... //your code goes here}`.

Comment: Another issue is that your `TestData` method returns `void` instead of `Task`. It can never be awaited by the caller.

Comment: The exception pretty much tells you all you need to know. I assume it happens on `DbContext.SomeDatas.ToListAsync()`? Chances are you somewhere call `DbContext.Dispose()` (either via direct method call or because you somewhere have that created in a `using`)

Comment: @AntonNorko: Good catch. Pretty sure that's the cause of the error actually. There's only a few select cases where async void is appropriate, and virtually none of them apply to web applications.

Comment: `it's just simplied version. this method returns list of data` ← You need to provide an [mcve], not pseudo-code. We can only go on the code and information you share and right now everyone is guessing because of the lack of an [mcve].

Comment: Where are you assigning something to your DbContext?

Answer (score 0):

```
using(DbContext db = new DbContext()) {
    data = await db.SomeData.ToListAsync();
}
```

using will be responsible for dispose resources.

Comment: You should virtually never use `using` with a `DbContext`. It should injected.

Comment: @ChrisPratt could you please explain why one should avoid `using` with a `DbContext`?

Comment: There's a host of reasons. `DbContext` is designed to be long-lived, keeping at least request-scope. When you use `using` on it like this, you break object cache, fixup, and other optimizations, as well as open the possibility for errors caused by lazy-loading or even just having objects attached to different contexts. In short, it creates a mess.

Comment: In this particular case, the exception the OP is getting clearly indicates that the problem is caused by the object being disposed, so telling them to dispose it isn't going to help.

Comment: Afaik, `DbContext` is not designed to be `long-lived` but rather to be a `unit-of-work`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?view=entity-framework-6.2.0
Would love to read where it is explained why keeping a single `DbContext` alive is the better option then creating many `DbContext`s @ChrisPratt

Comment: Unit of work should be long-lived. The whole point of a unit of work is that you're coordinating what's happening in multiple repositories (i.e. transactions). If you're creating and disposing your unit of work with each operation, you cannot do anything transactionally. The same applies to `DbContext`, but to an extreme, as it has tons of other optimizations and functionality that depend on the context actually hanging around.

Comment: As far as "where it is explained why keeping a single `DbContext` alive is the better option", I'm not aware of anything where it's so directly stated, but you need look no further than the fact that `AddDbContext` registers it as scoped. If it was intended to be disposed all the time, it would be transient.